# There exists an isomorphim of an infinite direct sum and an infinite product of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, abelian-groups

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, it is shown that for $n\geq 2$ a map
$$ \oplus_{\alpha \in A}\pi_n(S^n) \to  \pi_n(\vee_{\alpha\in A}S^n)$$ induced by $S^n\to \vee_{\alpha\in A}S^n$ is an isomorphism even if $A$ is infinite. Combined with the fact that the natural map $\pi_n(\vee_{\alpha\in A}S^n) \to \pi_n(\Pi_{\alpha\in A}S^n)$ is an isomorphism in this situation as the pair $(\pi_{\alpha\in A}S^n,\vee_{\alpha\in A}S^n))$ is $(2n-1)$-connected, is this showing that the map at the top induces a (non-canonical) isomorphism from $\mathbb Z^{\oplus A} \to \mathbb Z^{\Pi A}$ for any set $A$? Also, is there an algebraic way to decribe the map?

Comment: No, there is no such isomorphism (they don't have the same cardinality if $A$ is countable, e.g.), and the natural map you describe is not an isomorphism either.